# Angular 16 Hydration - API calls are happening in Server Side and Client Side

Tags: angular, nestjs, hydration, angular-ssr

In my Angular 16.2.0 ssr project with Nest.js, the API calls are happening on the server side and client side as well, though the provideClientHydration is provided.
I can see that the console msg say hydrated.

```
Angular hydrated 62 component(s) and 889 node(s), 0 component(s) were skipped.
```

And also i can see the API responses have been added to the dom,

[image]

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thank you.